# Toggle SearchBar in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, animation, searchbar

I have a `TableView` along with a search button at the bottom. I would like for the search button to cause a `SearchBar` to pop in at the top and be brought into focus. Otherwise, there should be no `SearchBar` showing.

It's easy enough to put a search bar above the `TableView`, but is there a way to hide/show it with animation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the `-[UITableView scrollRectToVisible:animated:]` method? I think the `UISearchBar` view is usually just a header view on the table, so you should be able to ask the table view to scroll up to show the search bar.

Comment: That works, however the search bar is still visible by default since it has to be assigned as the `tableView.tableHeaderView`. Also, it's sort of clunky as the tableview must scroll all the way to the top to access the `UISearchBar`. I'm looking for a way to display no `UISearchbar` until the Search button is tapped. For now, a `UISearchDisplayController` is close to what I want, though it still doesn't hide the `UISearchBar` initially.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me.  Hope it helps.

Call [self hideSearchBar] in your viewWillAppear (this will hide the search bar initially).

Your search button should have the following action:

```
- (IBAction)searchIconButtonClicked {
    if (self.searchDisplayController.isActive || (self.tableView.contentOffset.y < 44)) {
        if (self.searchDisplayController.isActive) {
            self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.text = nil;
            [self.searchDisplayController setActive:NO animated:YES];
            [tableView reloadData];
        }
        [self hideSearchBar];
    } else {
        [self.patientTableView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1) animated:YES];
    }
}

- (void)hideSearchBar {
    //NSLog(@"Hiding SearchBar");        
    [self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,44)];
}
```